# How do I make a connection to a MySQL database using ColdFusion?

Tags: mysql, sql, web-services, coldfusion

I have Adobe ColdFusion 10 installed on my computer and registered with a free website on 000webhost.com. However, when I tried to connect I got this error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: ssss
>   java.sql.SQLException: Timed out trying to establish connection   The
>   root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out trying to
>   establish connection

This is what I typed in the ColdFusion connector:

- CF Data Source Name: `ssss`
- Database: `a9156701_25`
- Server: `mysql3.000webhost.com Port 3306`
- Username: `a9156701_sayood`
- Password: `*******`

I don't know if the problem is with the free web host or the way I added the data source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your datasource looks correct. You are not allowed to connect remotely to the database. I found this [mentioned in their forums](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/35499-error-connection.html#post188889):

> 11-12-2013, 05:45 PM: Are you trying to connect remotely? (not
>   allowed) Your files have to be on the server.

Comment: is there any free web hosting that allow to connect remotely ?. if not what is good  web hosting that allow remote connect to database

Comment: Maybe http://www.freesqldatabase.com/freemysqldatabase/ is right for you. I would prefer to pay a small amount and have a reliable database.

Comment: that was helpful really :DDDDDD

Comment: after 3 hours making search on internet, i can see to that problem is happening by to this doesn't work locally.
Thank´s @da_didi